# using FB UI to prompt user with an error mesasge

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-ui

Is it possible to prompt a simple dialog using JS-SDK, FB UI, e.g. "The maximum upload size is 25MB.". There should be only the dialog and a button with a custom label.

Answer (score 0):

There are only a set number of [facebook dialogs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/). You will need to make your own UI for this.